# Erro ao colocar site em opencart em domínio

Tags: opencart

galera desenvolvi um [site](http://www.agenciafront.com.br/trustech/index.php?route=common/home) em opencart porem ao colocar ele no meu domínio ele aparece uns erros estranhos alguém sabe o que pode ser segue o print abaixo com as mensagens de erro os erros podem ser visualizados no link disponibilizado acima também.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: os erros aparecem no topo da página e no final da página lá no roda pé

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todas essas mensagens não são erros e sim avisos.

Para desabilitar erros e avisos no php é bem simples. Basta colocar essa linha de código no inicio do seu index:

`<?php
    error_reporting(0);
?>`

Dessa forma os erros ficaram visíveis somente no back-end, e não no front pro usuário se "assustar".

Esse post explicar mais sobre esse assunto: https://aldeyf.wordpress.com/2013/11/11/desabilitar-avisos-de-erro-php-warnings/

Answer (score 1):

Muitas vezes são erros que não impactam em nada, por ser warning, você pode desabilitar os erro direto nas configurações do opencart.

um deles deve ser resolvido habilitando o fopen da hospedagem.